# Python pandas write to excel with given condition

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins

My requirement is to read data from database and write to excel sheet and send it to team via email, in every 5 minutes, via Jenkins with given condition. Condition is that if no data is fetched from DB, no emails, if same data is fetched for more than 3 times then no email further for same data, shoot email only when different data is fetched. I am writing code in python 2.7, this version is available to me.
I am able to fetch data from DB and write to excel using Pandas and send over email, every 5 minutes.
I have tried to write "no. of times same data is fetched" to a file and then use it but somehow things are not working.

Comment: I suggest you read the following post about writting good questions in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Include Edit your question and include the code you used and any error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, btw I got my issue resolved by using pickle modile.